# replace the old application with the new one without installation

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

my client already has an app in the play store.
he asked me to create an update for his application and it is already ready.
how to replace the old application with the new one let us know that I only have the package and the Keystore ?
can I do this without the user doing anything ?
as if sometimes I open an application and notice changes without installing a new update

Comment: We can do it if your app written by React native and the exits app in Play store has been implement Code push, and you didn’t update native code

Comment: otherwise, you must update app on store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - You have an app live in the store, written in react-native, and you want to update the app with a new version, but you don't want the user to have to go to the play store and click the update button, you want to deliver an update to your app without going through the play store.

If that sounds correct then code push is the way to go, but if your current app does not have code push installed and setup, you won't be able to get THIS version to deliver that way, but future updates could.

The caveat to using code push is that you can't make any native changes to your app, you can only update your .js files and the assets that ship with the app. Any updates - such as new packages - that have native components will not be able to be pushed with code push and will require a full native app update through the store.

Code push has moved to app center. [Check out the site here](https://appcenter.ms/?utm_source=CodePush&utm_medium=Azure).

If I did not understand your question, please feel free to update your question to clarify what you are exactly trying to accomplish, and what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: oh thank you, this is what I want.. actually the older version is not written by react native so I think is not possible but that's good to know code push I will implement it in this version for futur updates. Thank you